# Why should i use fusion.js by uber instead of create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, uber-api

Uber says that it comes with a pre-configured optimized boilerplate and plugin based architecture. Does plugin based architecture mean it is something like gulp?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what it is - except that it may not be - come to think of it, it's nothing like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fusion.js developer here. Create-react-app is certainly a nice tool, but lacks a lot of things that a more advanced application will need. Fusion.js ships with server rendering and server-side code out of the box. You can find more in our write-up here: https://fusionjs.com/docs/getting-started/framework-comparison#create-react-app

The plugin system allows for encapsulation of both server logic and client logic within a single plugin. You can then take a released plugin and register all of it within a single line. For example, you are able to register the Redux plugin within a single line of code, or the Router, which includes server rendering, providers,  bundle splitting, and HMR integration.

Comment: now the redux toolkit is out, it is much easier to stitch redux within the application with a single function call.